# Hard code data instead of importing data while plotting using d3 library

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to plot a bar chart for the following data:

```
name      value
Locke      4
Reyes      8
Ford       15
Jarrah     16
Shephard   23
Kwon       42
```

Following is a "html/javascript" code to plot a simple bar chart in which the data is getting imported using d3.tsv

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart rect {
 fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 420,
barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
.attr("width", width);

d3.tsv("data2.txt", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

 var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

 bar.append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
  .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

 bar.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}

</script>
```

When I open the above script in a browser, i am able to get the bar chart without any issue.

Now when I replace the following lines in the above code

```
 d3.tsv("data2.txt", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
```

with:

```
    var data = [
  {name: "Locke",    value:  4},
  {name: "Reyes",    value:  8},
  {name: "Ford",     value: 15},
  {name: "Jarrah",   value: 16},
  {name: "Shephard", value: 23},
  {name: "Kwon",     value: 42}
];
```

I am not getting the bar chart. When I open the modified code with the abve mentioned change in the browser, it is blank.

What am I doing wrong? I have just started coding in javascript, so I may have been doing a very silly mistake. Any help will be geatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Data grabbed from tsv file is available within a callback function(error, data) which is a third parameter to a d3.tsv function. If you want to use data from js object instead you need to remove the lines

```
d3.tsv("data2.txt", type, function(error, data) {
```

and

```
});
```

and put your 'data' variable before using it.
Complete example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ofo615kj/1/).